# Matlab: How to color single cell of a surf plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, geometry-surface

I'm trying to differentiate the color of a single cell of a surf plot based on the Z function value, in particular:
X, Y are (nxm) matrix and define a surface;
Z is a ones(nxm) which has some particular points set to 3 or 4 or 5

I'm trying to have a surf plot where the single grid cells with 3,4 or 5 value are colored differently then all the other surface grid cells.

here's the code and the image I'm getting (in this specific case there's only 1 Z point with value =3):

[image]

```
figure;surf(X,Y,Z)
```

In this specific example my goal is to color RED the grid cell correspondent to the peak .Is there a way to obtain it?

thnks in advance

Comment: the point is that using colormap I'm still not getting the grid cell with the peak colored, for example, in RED.

Comment: Perhaps you need to change the number of bits in your colormap? But also, have you tried it when the peak in not on the edge? Remember that is the the vertex and not the face that has the value, and the value is then signed to a face next to (after) that vertex. So if it's on the end, you won't see the colour as it will be off your surface.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, colormap is the answer. The hard part is setting it up properly. The trick is to make the colormap larger than you need, say 10x3, make some bins inside colormap, and then scale your Z to fit into those bins. For example:

```
cmap(1, 1) = [0 0 0];
cmap(2:4, 1) = [0 0 1];
cmap(5:7, 1) = [0 1 0];
cmap(8:10, 1) = [1 0 0];
colormap(cmap);
```

This makes colormap bins, which you must fit your Z values into. You'll need to write the Z-value translation code. You need to write something that turns any element of Z which is 5, for example, into 10.

I've done this for a similar problem using images, so if you work with me we can get you an exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure

```
colormap(jet)
```

doesn't work here?
One of the ways i've done this is that in the GUI, you can manually edit teh colormap values in the colormap.

Then, just print out the colormap

```
cmap = colormap
```

And then these values can be used in your function.